# Как работает декоратор?

Tags: javascript

```
function slow(x) {
  alert(`Called with ${x}`);
  return x;
}

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(x) {
    if (cache.has(x)) { 
      return cache.get(x);
    }

    let result = func(x);

    cache.set(x, result);
    return result;
  };
}

slow = cachingDecorator(slow); // *

alert( slow(1) ); // slow(1)
alert( "Again: " + slow(1) );
```

Как это работает? Мы сохраняем `cachingDecorator(slow)` в переменную slow, которая у нас является функцией. Т. е. вставили функцию#1 в другую функцию#2 и тем самым присвоили все в функцию#1.
Если есть источники, где более ясно все объясняется , пожалуйста, скиньте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: _переменную slow, которая у нас является функцией_ - не переменная является функцией, а __значение__ переменной. При присваивании просто поменялось (заменилось) значение переменной.

Comment: @grundy если у нас изменилось значение переменной, как тогда выполняется это `let result = func(x);` Ведь `slow = cachingDecorator(slow);`?
Я просто не могу это воспринять)

Comment: отлично выполняется. Передав `slow` в качестве параметра, ты связал имя аргумента `func` с исходной функцией. То что потом переменной `slow` присвоили новое значение, никак не влияет на исходную функцию.

Comment: "вставили функцию#1 в другую функцию#2 и тем самым присвоили все в функцию#1." - какое еще требуется объяснение?

Comment: @grundy То есть функция `slow` уже не будет существовать с данным именем, но будет связана с `func`?

Comment: функция, как существовала, так и продолжит существовать. С этой стороны ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cachingDecorator()` - создает замыкание, то есть сочетания функции, переданной в нее, и области видимости, привязанной к этой функции.

В данном случае, метод `cachingDecorator()` (чтобы не путать) возвращает анонимную функцию, которая имеет доступ к следующим данным:

- переданная в `cachingDecorator()` функция (`slow()`)
- созданный для анонимной функции словарь (`cache = Map()`).

В словарь записываются данные вызовов функции `slow`. В качестве ключа записывается параметр, с которым она вызвана. А в качестве значения - возвращенные данные.

Таким образом, анонимная функция "запоминает" свои вызовы. При повторном вызове с этим же параметром она просто возвращает данные из "кэша", не вызывая повторно функцию `slow()`.

Выражение `cachingDecorator(slow)` создает своего рода кэширующую оболочку над функцией `slow()`. Внутри этой оболочки будет вызвана функция `slow()` только в том случае, если с таким же параметром она не вызывалась.

Выражение `slow = cachingDecorator(slow)` переопределяет переменную `slow` - назначая ей новую функцию-оболочку. Для того, чтобы проще понять это преобразование, можно объявление функции `slow()` переписать следующим образом:

```
var slow = function(x){return x}; // alert я убрал
```

Это почти эквивалентное выражение для `function slow(x){return x}`. В результате объявляем переменную `slow` и присваиваем ей объект-функцию. Эту функцию можно вызывать с помощью круглых скобок, передавая внутри необходимые параметры. Все так же.

Поэтому в выражении `slow = cachingDecorator(slow)` мы в эту же переменную кладем другую функцию, но которая хранит "знание" прежней функции, а также имеет доступ к словарю ее вызовов.

```js
// slow() - простая функция, возвращающая переданный в нее аргумент как есть.

function slow(x) {
  return x;
}

// cachingDecorator() - функция, принимающая в качестве параметра другую функцию как объект
// создает замыкание для переданной функции (сохраняемую индивидуальную область видимости)
// возвращает анонимную функцию, имеющую доступ к данным вмещающей ее функции

function cachingDecorator(func) { 
  let cache = new Map(); // "Словарь" для хранения данных замыкания
    
    // анонимная (безымянная функция), принимающая один аргумент - x
  return function(x) {
    if (cache.has(x)) {     // Если в словаре есть ключ == x
      return cache.get(x);  // Возвращаем значение под этим ключом
    }
    // Иначе вызываем, переданную в cachingDecorator, функцию.
    // Возваращенный результат присваиваем переменной result
    let result = func(x);

    cache.set(x, result); // Записываем данные в cache под ключом x
    return result;        // Возвращаем результат
  };
}

// Переопределяем переменную slow
// Теперь она содержит результат вызова cachingDecorator(slow)
// т.е. она хранит функцию, имеющую доступ к пустому словарю и объекту-функции slow()
slow = cachingDecorator(slow);

// Первый вызов новой функции с параметром 1
// В словаре ключа 1 нет -> вызываем функцию (== slow(1))
// Возвращаемое значение (1) записываем в словарь под ключом 1
console.log( slow(1));

// Повторный вызов функции с параметром 1
// В словаре содержится ключ 1
// Возвращаем значение из словаря под ключом 1 - 1
console.log( "Again: " + slow(1) );
```